# objective-C #import with route

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I used a third-party SDK, I followed the guide to import the SDK package into my project by drawing the floder into the project navigator.

The guide show I can use it by adding:
`#import "package.h"`
but I got an error  `'package.h' file not found`.

Then I found using 　`#import "SDK/a/package.h"`  is OK.

The sample project given with the SDK also just use the name without path.

Am I use the wrong way to import the Code? or did I miss some steps before using them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "Target membership" option in project navigator for header file, under "Utility view".

If that does not work, make sure your ".h" file it's added on Build phases -> Headers -> Public.